# Trouble Recovering Windows using System Image Backup

Tags: windows-10, system-restore

I bought my laptop `Lenovo-Z51 70` few months ago, with it I got `Windows 8.1`. Then when `Windows 10` update came, I updated my windows to windows 10 and made a `System Image Backup` and stored it in my external hard disk. Now because of some issues my windows got corrupted. When I try to recover my windows using my system image backup from my hard disk I'm getting this error message

> The system image restore failed Error
>
> details: The processor architecture or OS version of Windows Recovery Environment is not the same as that of the computer that was backedup.....

[image]

Can anybody tell me, how can I resolve this issue.

Comment: You cannot restore a Windows 7 restoration image if you are running Windows 10.  If you created the image while you were running Windows 10, indicate which build you were using at the same, and what build your currently using.  You should edit your question to include this information.

Comment: @Ramhound read question once again its clearly mentioned.

Comment: **I have read your question multiple times.**  *It isn't clear what version of Windows you were using when the image was created.*  **You failed to answer** my other questions I had.  Please edit your question, to include the information I requested, otherwise the question is not clear.

Comment: What version of the WinRE are you using in that particular screenshot?

Comment: @Ramhound At first I got Windows 8.1 in my laptop then I updated it to windows 10 and then made the backup. Hence I have windows 10 backup.

Comment: What build of Windows 10 were you using when you created the backup?

Comment: @Ramhound I don't know that.

Comment: It's important information, can you estimate, if you did it before or after Nov 2015?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to boot Windows 7, 8 or 10 install DVD. You can create it by `Windows Media Creation Tool` https://www.microsoft.com/cs-cz/software-download/windows10

Then select Windows Recovery tools and try to recover your image through it.

Otherwise you can copy by DVD recovery tool's command line or linux live distribution the image to volume.

If you are in command line in Recovery tool, you can by use of this command (paths are random):

```
wbadmin start recovery -backupTarget:D:/foo -recoverytarget:C:/biggerfoo
```

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc742070(v=ws.11).aspx

If you don't know which volume is which, you can use:

```
diskpart
select disk 0
list volume
```

Comment: @PřemyslŠťastný I do not have Windows DVD, I've only got system image backup of Windows 10.

Comment: Is it better now?

Comment: @PřemyslŠťastný I didn't get you

Comment: @Atinesh Which part exactly?

Comment: @Atinesh Download one.  "Not having an installation disk" to Windows 10 isn't really a good answer when you can create one by sinplying downloading the Windows 10 ISO

Comment: @Ramhound You mean bootable windows 10 disc. I have bootable windows 10 usb stick.

Comment: but You said you didn't have one?

Answer (score -1):

What do you mean by corrupted? Ordinarily you can use Přemysl Šťastný's way of reparing your system by using the advanced boot options of windows 10. Start your computer and when it tries to load windows shut it down by pressing the power off key for a few seconds. Then when it starts up again it should actually give you the option to use the Windows repair tools to fix your system. Use the console and follow with Přemysl Šťastný's solution.

Comment: More Precisely, I was using Malwarebytes software to remove some malware from my system. But by mistake, it also deleted some important windows files, which lead to freezing the task bar.

Answer (score -1):

Did you create a system repair disc (SRD) at the same time?  That SRD determines the version of OS that is supported to restore.  The good news is you can find someone else with the same OS architecture, and make a SRD on that machine that should then work on your machine.

Comment: No I'vent created system repair disc (SRD).